# Audio streaming solutions for 3 or more channel sound?

Tags: ios, macos, audio, streaming, icecast

I have a simple iOS application, where I want to stream 3 or more separate channels from OSX server to different iOS clients.

The problem is that I want to try simpler ways of implementing server streaming part, without resorting to native AudioQueue and CoreAudio services. For instance, icecast + darkice combination seemed like a good solution, but it turns out darkice can't work with more than 2 channels.

Are there any somewhat simple audio streaming libraries or solutions for OSX? Alternatively, what is the quickest way to implement audio streaming on iOS/OSX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made a project in iOS + Pure Data that does this for me: https://github.com/Apolotary/NetsendPD